# jQuery Ui Spinner disappear in woocommerce cart page after updating cart

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-ui, woocommerce

I've stuck into a problem and couldn't find the solution.

I am using jquery ui spinner in product quantity for the min/max quantity for each product so that user can increase the quantity on addition of min quantity of that particular product, like if product A has the min quantity of 12 then the quantity increase like 24,36 and so on... It works completly fine

Problem is whenever i update the cart the spinner disappears and can not increase product quantity according to min quantity. but when i refresh the page everything works fine..

Here is my jquery code

```
var min_val=0;
var step_val=0;

jQuery(function ($) {

    $(".qty").attr("onkeydown", "return false");
    var min_val=$(".qty").attr("min");
    var step_val=$(".qty").attr("step", min_val);
    $(".qty").spinner();
    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $(".qty").spinner();
    });

});
```

I think after ajax call for updating cart disable my js and after that it wont re-initialize.

i have used ajaxStop() as but didn't work

Can any one help me how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either disable ajax on cart page by inserting code in functions.php

```
function cart_script_disabled(){
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-cart' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cart_script_disabled' );
```

or if you don't want to diable the AJAX request use this

```
jQuery(function ($) {

 $(".qty").attr("onkeydown", "return false");
    var min_val=$(".qty").attr("min");
  var step_val=$(".qty").attr("step", min_val);
  $(".qty").spinner();

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){

$(".qty").attr("onkeydown", "return false");
    var min_val=$(".qty").attr("min");
var step_val=$(".qty").attr("step", min_val);
    $(".qty").spinner();
$("#uc").removeAttr("disabled");
});

});
```